# Injectable type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I 'm writing a game library. I have it working with a hierarchy of instances of

```
class Animation a where
    event :: a -> Event -> Writer [Event] a
    paint :: a -> IO ()
```

Here `event` handles an event and possibly emits new events for its parent to see (for example an exit `Button` could wait for `MouseClickEvent` and emit a `CloseEvent`) and `paint` does painting. My generic use case would be

```
--a user defined Animation, say a button
data MyChild = MyChild
instance Animation Child where
    ... anything

--a library defined Animation which is a composition of other animations
data LibWrapper = LibWrapper (Event -> Writer [Event] LibWrapper) (IO ())
mkWrapper :: (Animation a) => a -> LibWrapper
mkWrapper a = LibWrapper (\ev -> mkWrapper <$> event a ev) (paint a)
instance Animation LibWrapper where
    event (LibWrapper e _) = e
    paint (LibWrapper _ p) = p

--a user defined Animation for which the 'event' and 'paint' will be called 
data MyRoot = MyRoot LibWrapper
instance Animation MyRoot where
    event (MyRoot a) ev = MyRoot <$> event a ev
    paint (MyRoot a) = paint a

game = MyRoot (mkWrapper Child)
```

Now I want to allow custom events. That is,

```
class Animation a e where
    event :: a -> e -> Writer [e] a
    paint :: a -> IO ()
```

The trouble is that I can't get `LibWrapper` (`instance Animation LibWrapper anyevent`) to contain a more restricted `MyChild` (`instance Animation  MyChild MyEvent`). I tried parametrizing `LibWrapper` and having `instance Animation (LibWrapper event) event` but Haskell seems to take the two occurrences of `event` as unrelated and I don't know what to do about it.

I've also considered

```
class Animation a where
    event :: a e -> e -> Writer [e] (a e)
    paint :: a e -> IO ()
```

Then it's `LibWrapper MyEvent` that contains a `MyChild MyEvent` and that's fine. But I don't have a way to define `instance MyChild MyEvent` any more, do I?

I'd much prefer to have `MyEvent` specified in the type of `MyRoot` however, if there exists a way to pass it as a parameter to my library module, that would be acceptable too.

**EDIT**

Just as I posted the question, I though to try

```
class Animation a e where
    event :: a e -> e -> Writer [e] (a e)
    paint :: a e -> IO ()
```

...just in case. Of course, it worked. I still don't really understand the type magic goingt on here. I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Your specification for "allow custom events" is unclear.  So I cannot advise on the right way to structure this.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: As I wrote this I had a `data LibEvent = MouseMove Int Int | KeyPress Char | ...` defined in my library module. Past event generation nothing in my library actually used these events so I thought should be able to write `data MyEvent = MouseMove Int Int | SomethingRelevantToTheGame | ...` and a function `LibEvent -> MyEvent` and to have my instances of `Animation` use the `MyEvent` as if it had been defined in the library.

Comment: I think Event should be a type class. You could make something like `instance Event e => Animation (Libwrapper e) e where ...`

Answer (score 1):

The magic I can explain, and to be clear I will ignore `event`.  The compiler sees

```
module Anim where

class Animation a e where
    paint :: a -> IO ()

module A where

data A1 ; data E1

instance Animation A1 E1 where paint A1 = print "i"

module Main where

import Anim; import A

main = paint A1
```

What should 'paint' do?  Note that `paint A1` has no information about `E1`.

Now imagine I add module B and import this into main:

```
module B where

import Anim; import A

data E2

instance Animation A1 E2 where paint A1 = print "j"
```

Now `main = paint A1` obviously cannot distinguish which instance you mean.  The Haskell standard requires that adding `import B` to `module Main` cannot affect the instance used in previously working code.  So `main` is rejected with or without `module B`.

This sort of thing is what type and data "families" are for (and the older functional dependencies).  This requires more reading of the [GHC user manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/type-families.html) to fully grasp.  But the upside is that there are at least three ways there to let you tell GHC that A1 should always imply E1.  For instance: associated type synonyms could work like this:

```
class Animation a where
    type Event a :: *
    event :: a -> Event a -> Writer [Event a] a
    paint :: a -> IO ()

instance Animation A1 where
    Event A1 = E1
    event = ...
    paint = ...
```

Comment: Actually, just `class Animation a e where event :: a -> e -> Writer [e] a` is not good either (no ambiguity there).